# Webstorm Support for ionic/cordova run configuration

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, webstorm

I'm running Running UBUNTU 16.04 with WebStorm 2016.2.3 and am getting errors when I attempt to configure the run configuration. [image]

It's asking me to 'Correct the path to PhoneGap/Cordova executable' despite my path being correct. I experience the same thing when I enter the path to cordova too. What is wrong?

Comment: please try starting Webstorm from terminal using webstorm.sh - does the problem persist?

Comment: Fantastic, running webstorm from the terminal worked! Why should this be the case? How can I run Webstorm from my Launcher correctly?

Comment: Most probably the issue is that node can't be found in your PATH... NVM patches environment variables on terminal startup only. If the IDE is launched from Terminal, it inherits Terminal environment (including modified PATH environment variable, added NVM_DIR env var, etc). In that case, there are normally no problems with loading ionic, etc.
If you're using bash as shell, workaround could be the the following: edit your Webstorm launcher and set command to /bin/bash -l -c "/path/to/webstorm.sh. This command will perform bash login and after that will run webstorm.sh.